# Add control from content page in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page that looks something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>    
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I use this design in all pages except one where i would like to add a button right after the first label - lbl1 (both of them to be on same row), and on the second row to see the second label.
My question is how could I achieve this from a content page (from code-behind preferable)?

Comment: create a button with display none., on that particular contant page find button with javascript and change its css

Comment: At the moment that is what i did, but I don't like adding a button with display:none on a master page that is used in a hundred pages, while the button is used only in one page

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Create `<asp:Button runat="server" Visible="false" ... />` which by default have `Visible = false`. In the page which you want to see the button find the button and make it `Visible = true`.

**When the Control is not visible it is not render, this is equal to not existing for other pages !**

Comment: Thanks, I did not knew that if a control is not visible means not existing. I mean I know the page doesn't render it, but I just find it, well, not very code-wise in doing it so

Comment: @next_user yes you can check it with View Page Source in the browsers. If the answer helped you, you can mark it as correct.